# How to build a Perl Socket Server?

Tags: json, perl, sockets, server, multiprocessing

I have found a few sparse resources on the matter, but i am looking to build a Perl server as a "microservice". More specifically a web application in LAMPhp/Perl/MariaDB in a SOA format.

What is the best way to go about building an efficient Perl server for our backend? The Web Tier opens a PHP stream TCP socket to a particular Perl server for a particular "service" (high-level service). That server must service many Web servers' requests asynchronously. The service then either connects directly to MySQL to fetch an answer (simple case) or must do some computational work to generate an answer.

My naive implementation is single-tasking:

```
use IO::Socket::INET;
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON::XS qw(encode_json decode_json);

$| = 1;

my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
    LocalHost => '0.0.0.0',
    LocalPort => '7000',
    Proto => 'tcp',
    Listen => 5,
    Reuse => 1
);

while(1) {
        my $client_socket = $socket->accept();
        my $client_address = $client_socket->peerhost();
        my $client_port = $client_socket->peerport();
        my $client_json = "";
        $client_socket->recv($client_json, 1024);
        my $client_data = decode_json $client_json;
        %response = %{process_request($client_data)};
        $reply_json = encode_json(\%response);
        $client_socket->send($reply_json);
        shutdown($client_socket, 1);
}
```

So, there are obviously problems with this, as it is a a copy-paste example from the documentation. It handles a single socket/request at a time serially.

My question is: "What are best practices in Perl to build a server than can efficiently multiplex and process many incoming requests"?

My own thought on the matter is build a 'select' or 'epoll' main process that forks off to a small pool of worker threads via a Thread::Queue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This question is not a great fit for Stack Overflow because it's too broad, and it sounds like you also might be asking for recommendations on libraries, off-site resources, etc. Having said that, I would attempt something in [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org), and then come back and ask specific questions when you run into specific problems.

Comment: http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook

Comment: What kind of data do you want to submit?

Comment: @MattJacob yeah, this question is very broad, but i'd hoped it was specific enough to get some direction on. I appreciate the pointers to Mojolicious, ill do my due diligence and research it.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using either a complete Framework like Mojolicious, or Dancer, or a Package like Net::Server. Quoting from its perldoc:

```
   "Net::Server" is an extensible, generic Perl server engine.

   "Net::Server" attempts to be a generic server as in "Net::Daemon" and "NetServer::Generic".  It includes with it the ability to run as an
   inetd process ("Net::Server::INET"), a single connection server ("Net::Server" or "Net::Server::Single"), a forking server
   ("Net::Server::Fork"), a preforking server which maintains a constant number of preforked children ("Net::Server::PreForkSimple"), or as a
   managed preforking server which maintains the number of children based on server load ("Net::Server::PreFork").  In all but the inetd type,
   the server provides the ability to connect to one or to multiple server ports.
```

HTH

Comment: Ill look into the frameworks to see if they're what i need. Net::Server on the otherhand is forking, which means in the long run it will not work as a viable solution.